# CPT Archive with parent page

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, custom-post-type-archives

Is it possible to set a parent page to a CPT Archive? I used a plugin to add archives to the `nav_menu` section. That works.

But I also want the link to be `/parent/archive`.

Is there a plugin or programmatic way to achieve this?

Comment: "I used a plugin to add archives to the nav_menu section" - what does this plugin do exactly?

Comment: It adds CPT archives to the `nav_manu` nection so I can add archives to my nav_manus. The problem is, that they are to hierarchal related to each other. So when I add an archive as submenu item of a page and visit that archive, the page is not in "active" state.